# Full Outer Join with Hive on Spark: How to Optimize or Other Alternatives

Tags: join, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem where I need to match a dataset of discrete (in time) events to a dataset of non-overlapping intervals (right endpoints do not overlap), finding the interval each event takes place during. An example:

The events dataset:

```
event  timestamp
a      1
b      5
c      10
```

The intervals dataset:

```
interval  start  end
a         0      2
b         2      3
c         3      6
d         6      10
e         10     11
```

Ideally I would do this in hiveQL (ultimately I'm using Spark here) like so:

```
select a.*, b.interval
from event a
left outer join 
interval b
on a.t >= b.start and a.t <= b.end
```

But hive doesn't support non-equijoins (but spark SQL does???, is there a way to specify which gets used after `HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc);`) so I'm doing something like:

```
select a.*, b.interval
from event a
full outer join 
interval b
where a.t >= b.start and a.t <= b.end
```

I'm no expert on how Hive on Spark works, but this strategy I've used appears to be prohibitively slow (this is a toy example, I actually have several TB of data). Both events and intervals are very large tables, although intervals is usually several times larger. I've considered some alternate strategies:

(1) Interpolate to every possible timestamp in the intervals dataset like so:

```
interval start
a        0
a        1
b        2
c        3
c        4
c        5
...
```

So that I can use `on a.timestamp = b.start` as a join condition. I have no idea if that's going to be more efficient or not though.

(2) Union of both datasets + gaps and islands fill down:

I've also considered whether taking the union of the two datasets, creating something like this (let's call it tblu):

```
type     event  interval  timestamp   start  end
interval NA     a         NA          0      2
event    a      NA        1           NA     NA
interval NA     b         NA          2      3
interval NA     c         NA          3      6
event    b      NA        5           NA     NA
```

And then doing something like:

```
select a.*, 
(case when a.end < a.timestamp then NA else b.interval end) as interval 
from (
select event, timestamp, max(start) as start, max(end) as end from ( 
    select *, 
        sum(case when type = 'event' then 0 else 1 end) over (order by coalesce(start, timestamp)) as group
    from tblu
) i
group by event, timestamp ) a
left outer join 
interval b
```

to get the interval for each event.

I'm hoping someone can a) provide some insight into why my current implementation is so slow. I have some ideas, namely that the full join causes the operation to be memory bound and that it creates a ton of shuffles between nodes, but I'm not exactly sure. I'm also wondering if there are b) ways to speed up my current implementation outside of spinning up bigger and more machines. Finally, I'm most interested if anyone has any thoughts about c) alternate methods for doing this operation and if any of my alternate ideas are good ones. Are there any other hadoop ecosystem tools better suited for a large table to large table join like this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't understand the full-outer join. I do this kind of thing all the time, finding the time slot that a particular event falls into. Spark does support a join like this: `$"a.t" >= $"b.start" && $"a.t" < $"b.end"` and I find it to be very fast (incidentally, you probably want one `>=` and one `<`, not both `>=` and `<=`). But then again, I'm just doing a vanilla join, not full-outer. At most I would do a `left_outer` but only if I needed to identify events that didn't fall into a time slot.

Comment: I'm doing the full outer join because hive doesn't support the non-equijoin and I need I need some other hive features (like window functions). Up until this point I've been using the sqlContext.sql("") interface to do this. You may have a point that I could do this using the DataFrame.join method as non-equijoin conditions are permitted.

Also, I agree, one inequality should be strict.

Comment: I try not to use `sqlContext.sql("")` -- no particular good reason, other than I'm kind of done writing 35 line SQL queries.